# Какую САПР выбираете вы?

Tags: тестирование, сапр, интерпретатор

Собственно сабж.

Интересно в плане статистики, может увижу интересные ответы, а то **AutoCAD** да **AutoCAD**. А главное интерпретаторы. Лично мне **AutoLisp** не втыкает вообще. Я долго мучился создавая игру крестики-нолики на нем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная альтернатива автокаду - [Компас](http://kompas.ru/). Эта САПР достаточно распространена и достаточно функциональна. Правда, при работе с ней заметно, что сделана она неважно (видны мелкие дефекты рендеринга).

Вообще, САПР бывают разные. В определённых узких специализациях применяют, например, [SolidWorks](http://www.solidworks.com/) и [Pro Engineer](http://www.pro-technologies.ru/product/Pro-ENGINEER). Например, вторую особенно часто используют в кораблестроении (у нас в стране по крайней мере).

По поводу крестиков-ноликов: вы пытались забивать гвозди тряпкой для пыли. По этой причине у вас были проблем. Вы применяли его не по назначению и, вероятно, без должной подготовки ;)

Comment: Спасибо! 
Про SolidWorks и Pro Engineer даже и не слышал. 

Вот сам добавлю которые видел и щупал

-DIPTRACE ( http://www.diptrace.com ) небольшая но прикольная для рисования и разведения

-QUARTUS II

Comment: SolidWorks и Pro Engineer для твердотельного моделирования.. они умеют делать очень много в том числе вычислять всякие нагрузки, внутренние напряжения и т.п. Они предназначены для промышленного машиностроения.